# Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/api/users/siteUsers/[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object]: 400 Bad Request

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, angular11

I am trying to add a multi-select dropdown in angular 11 and .netcore 3.1 web api.
when i submit the dropdown, errors occur like this.
"Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/api/users/siteUsers/[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object]: 400 Bad Request"

backend

```
[Route("siteUsers/{id}")]
```

How can i pass the from frontend the data.

**Edit:**

Angular service.ts file

```
  CreateSiteUsersAsync(data: FormData, id: number) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/${this.basePath}/siteUsers/${id}`, data);
  }
```

.ts file

```
async onSubmitHandler() {
    const data = { ...this.userForm.value};

    await this.userService.CreateSiteUsersAsync(data,data.siteCode).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: You can't send http request like `/[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object]`. PRobably, problem is in your client code. Can you share your angular code.

Comment: @BarışCanYılmaz I have edited the post. see above

Comment: Also, can you share your backend code which you send post request.

Comment: it would appear your id is an array of objects, not a number

Answer (score 1):

A few things that is wrong with your function.

First `Route` is being specified, but the not the `Http` method. Meaning the default  method is `Get`. You cannot pass form data to a `Get` method. It should be, `Post`or `Put`. So first thing is add a http method:

```
[Route("siteUsers/{id}")]
[HttpPost]
```

or more elegantly:

```
[HttpPost("siteUsers/{id}")]
```

Next is the receival attributes where you get the data from. There are four options `[FromRoute]`, `[FromForm]`, `[FromQuery]` and `[FromBody]`.

By default C# uses `[FromQuery]`. So for both the `id` and the `data` you will need to specify where you search this data. See code below:

```
[HttpPost("siteUsers/{id}")]
public IActionResult MyEndpoint([FromRoute] id, [FromForm] data)
{
    ...
    
    return Ok();
}
```

You can also use `[FromBody]` instead of the `[FromForm]` tag since technically both are are from the body.